# on Arcgis Android SDK Getting codedvalues from ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-android, domains

i have arcgis mapview, and when user click on Mapview, i get point which is clicked after that i search with IdentifyParameters class and i am getting information about layers which is clicked place. But there is a problem, when i am getting information, alias and value is shown but my value has coded value so user see number but exactly value is string. how can i get codedvalues  ?

Answer (score 3):

Coded Value Domain represents details from a `FeatureLayer`.  This differs from a `ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer` as feature services are composed of features with geometry and attributes.  Features in a FeatureLayer can be displayed on a map, queried, edited, and selected.  You can get the `CodedValueDomain` from a `FeatureTable` in a `FeatureLayer` from a Feature Service.  Here is some sample code:

```
for (Layer layer : mMapView.getLayers()) {
  if(layer instanceof FeatureLayer){
    FeatureLayer fLayer = (FeatureLayer) layer; 
      for(Field field:fLayer.getFeatureTable().getFields()){
        if(field == Field.esriFieldTypeInteger){
          if(field.getDomain() instanceof CodedValueDomain){
            CodedValueDomain cvd = (CodedValueDomain) field.getDomain();
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Take a look at the following [SDK sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/FeatureServiceTableQuery) for an example usage in an app.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm wondering What If using featureLayer with QueryTask, how can I extract codedValueDomain ? I read all of sdk's documentation but couldn't find any solution :(

Comment: I've solved my issue with your approach. Cheers!! :)